# Was there any war won by the victim without sending forces to lands/seas/air of the attacker?

Tags: warfare

Was there ever in history a victim that won the war, remaining totally on its own lands? No sea, air, or land attacks on the lands of the attacker or their allies.

A necessary notice about what is "winning the war": I am NOT talking about "the moral win"!
The victim regains ALL their lands back - it is the minimal requirement.

For example, there was the Finland-Soviet Union Winter War (1939-1940) in which the Soviet Union attacked Finland but failed to achieve its objectives. In the end, the Soviet Union had to accept a peace deal that gave less territory to them than they had hoped for.

But it was not Finland's winning. It was merely the Soviets winning less than they wanted.

Why I am asking:
Nowadays the West left the target of Russian non-winning in the Ukranian war and almost wholely accepted that **the target of the West is Ukraine winning the war**. On the other hand, there is a heavy discussion about **if Ukraine can attack Russian lands**. And I am interested if that discussion has any sense providing we accepted the target.

Comment: The American revolutionary war. (technically John Paul Jones raided England, but it was trivial.)  The Haitian wars of independence,   Wars of Italian Unification.Possibly the Russo-Japanese war.  [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @MCW Amer. Rev. was a local revolt, not the aggression of one state against another. Italian Unification again - aggressor (Sardinia) won. And it did move troops to the victim. In the Russo-Japanese war of 1904/5 Japan was attacker, and Russia lost it. Again it has nothing in common with the question. About the preliminary research - I have given the closest example, as I see it. I don't think that more examples NOT answering the question would help.

Comment: I suspect the Vietnamese would make a case for themselves too.

Comment: Denmark won WWII without invading Germany or Japan (not sure about Bulgaria, though)

Comment: @T.E.D. Excellent example! I think it is a nice answer! Please, write it down as such. And foolish me, I tried to recall and to search, and missed that war.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Or sending anybody anywhere... A good joke :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. But haven't the Vietnamese attacked Cambodia which was a USA ally while reigned by Sihanouk?

Comment: @T.E.D. And there were no Vietnamese as such. There were northern and southern ones. There were two different states. I am not sure who really attacked the first, but there was a war between two Viet states, and USA started to help to southerns, and later started to participate, and lost. So, the Northerns occupied southern Vietnam. So, it was hardly a victory without victim armies going out of their land. So, sorry, it is an interesting answer, good for discussion and further thinking, but not the correct one.

Comment: @T.E.D. But your answer leads me to others. I think any war when the attacker came by the fleet to a far land and was thrown off, could serve.

Comment: @T.E.D. Due to your answer maybe I had found: the episode of The Peloponnesian War (431-404 BC), when Athens attacked the island of Sicily but was defeated by the Syracusan forces. Without Syracusan attacks on Athens or its allies. But I couldn't find that answer without yours. Could you post your answer, please?

Comment: Any of the recent wars in/invasions of Afghanistan (British/Russian/USA(NATO)) , where the locals merely eroded the invaders' will to stay.

Comment: Just about every war of (colonial) independence would match your requirements.

Comment: @Jos' point was what I was getting at. From the Vietnamese perspective, they were [one nation before the French came](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%AA_dynasty), and the next 200 years was largely them fighting to kick the foreigners out and run their own country. "South Vietnam" was just one more puppet state set up by the foreign oppressors a couple of decades before their final defeat.

Comment: The issue I have with posting this as an answer was that this appears to be a "yes or no" question that is (arguably trivially) "yes". I don't see why my answer would be considered any better (or worse) than anyone else's that had an example. Say Pieter's. Its just as "Yes" no matter who we mention. Hate to say this out, as I really do honestly appreciate you stepping up and trying to ask a question.

Comment: @T.E.D. 1. The question is set in the header, and the body does not contradict it.  Obviously, if the question says "if there was...", the answer supposes example(s) and reference(s), up to the traditions of SE. 2. Looking at two wars with different enemies, at different times as the one war, is utterly metaphoric, and I had mentioned that I am not asking about metaphors. 3. There is no Pieter among commenters. What do you mean?

Comment: @Jos Not "about every". On the contrary, mostly, independence wars included some operations outside of the colony land. For example, Vietnamese operations in Laos and Cambodia. But with "some of them", surely, you are right.

Comment: @KillingTime Excellent example! AFAIK, in the Soviet war there were Afghan operations in neighbouring states, but surely, as least two of three English wars were purely inside of Afghanistan.

Answer (score 2):

Dismissing the U.S. as a merely a "rebellion" is absurd; denying the very real manner in which the several "states" were self governing well before the Declaration of Independence.

Likewise, the Dutch rebellion (Eighty Years War) was won by the Dutch without ever attempting invasion of Spain.

Similarly for the Vietnamese (first against the French and then against the U.S.); the Swiss (against Habsburg Austria); the Franks against the Roman Empire; and, though it took centuries, the Spanish Reconquista against the Moorish invaders. How are you going to determine which conflicts "took to long" to be included?

In the Hundred Years War the French successfully threw out the English invaders without ever making any meaningful invasion of England. The Russians threw off the Mongol (ie Golden Horde) Yoke over centuries, gaining independence without ever invading Kazakstan. Likewise they threw out  the Polish-Lithuanians from Moscow, and regained independence, without ever invading their aggressor. The Chinese in World War Two were on the winning side though never invading Japan.

The list of eligibles for this is likely near endless.

Comment: Franks crossing the Limes looks very much like an expansion into the Roman empire to me, not like something very defensive.

Comment: If we're mentioning Vietnam, probably ought to also throw Afghanistan in there (like 3 times at least). But of course this list could grow to redicious lengths, which you say in the last line, and you gotta stop somewhere.

Comment: @T.E.D.: It was roughly: How many can I list in 60 seconds or so?

Comment: Possible additions: India and Alexander the Great? Greeks and Xerxes? Alexander Nevsky and Teutonic knights? Russo-Polish war (AFAIR, at that time they didn't invade Poland). Soviet Union and ANTANTA invasions (which were part of Civil War but being foreign invasions, see like they should count). Balcan wars of independence of all sorts?

Comment: @DVK:Yep. all good additions.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with all your examples. And the form you use, calling opponent names without any arguments, only pouring more and more "examples" is merely itself an example of a poor discussion... We had already found positive answers to the question, but they are different.

Comment: About the first example: English were sure they were colonists, who attacked the first, American ships attacked English, invasion of Canada in 1775 led by General Richard Montgomery, which aimed to capture Montreal and Quebec City, and the last, but the most important - in the Independence War puny troops of colonists were supported by a real army of really strong France, in the Anglo-French War (1778–1783). It is obvious that that example is inappropriate, for many reasons, but you are insisting... why?

Comment: @Gangnus: So, you disagree with my analysis (and likely downvoted my answer to reinforce the message). Good. Very good in fact. It is through such civil disagreement, and ensuing discussion, that we arrive at a better understanding of history, and perhaps even improve ourselves in the process. There are always nuances, and differences in interpretation of the significance of those nuances. Let the debate begin. The real point here is that you've asked a list question - by definition impossible of a definitive answer - not that you disagree with a subset of my listed examples

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I am delighted that you are looking positively at the discussion. Being a foreigner, I sometimes misunderstand the subtleties of expressions of feelings, and I understood you differently. ... Please, notice that I cannot analyze all items of your list in comments. So, let's start with the first one. Agreed? ... In my comment on May 3, I wrote, that the war 1775-83 colonists hardly were the defending site from the first hours, they did not win the war themselves, but they were merely the weakest ally in the coalition, they DID attack other lands belonging to England... So, what?